# signInWithEmailAndPassword (Ionic / Vue / Firebase) not resolving promise in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I've been struggling with this one for a while now and I've finally given up finding an answer to it, decided to ask my own question.

I have an Ionic 7 Vue app where I use Firebase Auth for user management. My code works perfectly in browsers and on Android and I can successfully sign users in. However on an iOS device or simulator it does not work.

When a user signs in I fire the following function (note that the auth object is valid, just not showing it here):

```
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword, UserCredential } from "firebase/auth";
const signInUser = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    try{
        const res = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        console.log("Successfully logged in with Firebase, UID: "+res.user.uid)
    }        
    catch(error){
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;

        console.error("Error Code: " + errorCode + " - Error Message: " + errorMessage);
    }
}
```

The error condition fires successfully, with the console.log showing the correct error. For example, if I input an incorrect password it console.logs a message saying such.

However, if I input the correct password and email, the console.log within the try block never executes. It simply hangs there and does nothing, as if the promise from the await never resolves. I also can't see any errors being thrown in my Xcode output.

An interesting note is that within the Firebase console it shows that the login actually does happen. This all indicates to me that it actually is working and somehow I'm not handling the resolved promise properly somehow.

I'm hoping that I've simply been silly with something trivial and someone here is going to point out some typo or something. Or that someone knows of some workaround to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use this way: `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` ? I tried to find signInWithEmailAndPassword on the auth module and couldnt find, maybe they are not maitaining that direct function correctly, Idk.  Check the way they are doing it here: https://github.com/firebase/snippets-web/blob/88aa8eb8210c90263eef7fe1f454cd6477a5a252/auth/email.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting Firebase support and doing many hours of searching I finally found the issue. Answering here in case someone else has this problem and is so completely driven insane by it as I was.

Apparently native environments don't gel with the `getAuth` function very well and can cause such issues. Setting up your `auth` object therefore requires you use `initializeAuth` instead. Before the change my code looked like this:

```
auth = getAuth(app);
setPersistence(auth,indexedDBLocalPersistence)
```

And to fix my problem I did this:

```
let auth: Auth;
if(isPlatform('hybrid')){
    auth = initializeAuth(app, {persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence})
}else{
    auth = getAuth(app);
    setPersistence(auth,indexedDBLocalPersistence)
}
```

Just remember to import all the needed items as they will not work otherwise:

```
import { initializeAuth, getAuth, setPersistence, indexedDBLocalPersistence, Auth } from "firebase/auth";
import { isPlatform } from "@ionic/vue";
```

Using this method I was able to get my iOS device and simulator to log in AND get a resolved, successful promise back from `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`

Answer (score 3):

Ideally this code should work as the code which you posted is nothing specific to browser or device. But I can suggest a workaround to just give a try, Can you please try to use `promise` instead of `async/await` to see if the issue persists.

By doing this you will get to know whether the issue is with the `async/await` behavior specifically.

```
const signInUser = (email: string, password: string) => {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then(res => {
        console.log("Successfully logged in with Firebase, UID: "+res.user.uid)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error Code: " + error.code + " - Error Message: " + error.message);
    })
}
```

If above approach will not work, Can you please check if any security applied on `iOS` to perform the firebase authentication by looking if your device has the necessary permissions for network access or not.

Comment: Hi Rohit, thanks for the answer. I have indeed tried a .then and .catch version with the same results. As I understand it, there is no specific permission needed for internet access - am I wrong about that? As per my question the login actually does happen - the promise simply ever resolves. Also, I do get an error response if there is an error so I do see that a connection is possible and occurring.

Comment: @Toiletduck Can you please try one more thing ? Try async/await without firebase auth API just to debug if firebase is causing that issue. As you said login happens then something is blocking in signInWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: thanks. I have run the try-catch version of the code with the Firebase Auth commented out and the console.log does run. It is certainly the Firebase code that is hanging. If the firebase code is included the console.log never runs, meaning the await hangs endlessly. I am currently looking into what security measures I may have missed in the set up of the project.

Comment: @Toiletduck Yeah, That's what I mentioned in the answer. There is something which is blocking `firebase` code to get executed seamlessly. Can you check with the firebase support.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using async/await and try/catch block. use .then and .catch and see if the result is same. I'am suggesting this because the firebase sdk had some issues when using it with asyn/await and try/catch block. please refer this
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1881#issuecomment-501886866

Comment: Thanks John. I have tried a .then() and .catch() with the same results unfortunately. Thank you for the link, however my errors do come through, it's the success condition that is not firing for some reason. Glad someone posted that though, in case some other poor soul finds this and its a solution for them.